# How to manage both landscape & portrait orientation in iOS application?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, screen-orientation, landscape-portrait

We are going to build ios application and graphics provided by client, if we need to manage both landscape & portrait orientation then do I need to ask for two different views graphics from client? I am a business analyst hence semi-technical.

I found that view controller can handle that event, but i am not sure do we need to separate psd files for portrait & landscape mode?

Answer (score 1):

First you don't use psd on the device, you just images (png, jpeg...)

Second, that depends on how your image is displayed in landscape. Is the same image when turning landscape as if it was in portrait? Then you don't need different images, just use the same one.

The only situation that you need different images is if the image changes when turning (change size, or change the whole image).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your client will need to provide graphics (background images etc) and layout information for both orientations. Needless to say, you only need two copies of elements that change depending on the orientation.

As Antonio MG pointed out, you won't be using psds files but jpegs and pngs. Pngs are a good choice for most types of images, although jpegs are a better at compressing photographs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for this
http://iphonesoul.blogspot.in/2012/12/device-orientation-in-ios.html

If you need anything else then you can ask me.

Comment: The question is about using different icons in landscape and portrait mode, your link is for supporting rotation not images.

Answer (score 0):

if your background images are not filled by only one color then you have to ask two different background images. Other images are depend on how they will look like on screen. If you say in both mode images can be in same size then no problem but if you want to change images size for example button, picture, textfield etc. then you need two different psd.